# Get all children of specified type regardless of level

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

How can I get all `<s:Images/>` from an MXML file regardless of where they are in the hierarchy of that file?

So for this:

```
<s:Group>
    <s:Image/>
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Image/>
        <s:Image/>
        <s:Image/>
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Image/>
            <s:Image/>
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Group>
```

I want to get all images from the first Group, regardless if they are contained within the Group itself or the VGroup or HGroup.

How can I do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursively, in pseudo code

```
myFunc(IContainer root):void
{
    for(i=0;i<root.numChildren;i++)
    {
        curChild = root.getChildAt(i);
        if(curChild is Image)
            doSomethingElse(curChild);
        if(curChild is IContainer)
            myFunc(curChild);
    }
}
```

Instead of IContainer since you have Flex 4 in your tags you need to look at the interfaces for that like:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/IVisualElementContainer.html

Answer (score 3):

```
filterImages([], this);
protected function filterImages(array:Array, child:Object):Array
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < child.numChildren; i++)
    {
        if(child.hasOwnProperty("getElementAt"))
        {
            var subChild:Object = child.getElementAt(i);
            if(subChild is Image)
            {
                array.push(subChild);
            }else
            {
                filterImages(array, subChild);
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```